# How to increment the value in lambda function inside re.sub?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to increment a value inside of a lambda function and substitute the value:

```
s = "245, 246, 171, 172"
mval = 1
res = re.sub(r'(\d+),?\s*', lambda m: "m"+str(mval)+"="+m.group(1)+"&"+mval+=1, s)
print(res)
```

I am expecting the below output:

```
m1=245&m2=246&m3=171&m4=172
```

The same thing in Perl as follows:

```
my $s='245, 246, 171, 172'; 
my $val=0;
$s=~s/(\d+),?\s?/$val++,'m'.$val.'='.$1.'&'/ge; 
print $s
```

But I don't know how to increment inside the lambda function.

Comment: lambdas are limited in Python.  lots of other ways to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: btw, perl one can be simplified to `"m".++$val."=$1&"` and would have `&` at end as well.. is that needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead on lambdas and regex's, how about using just native Python functions like:

#### Code:

```
new_s = '&'.join('m{}={}'.format(i+1, s.strip())
                 for i, s in enumerate(have_s.split(',')))
```

#### How does this work?:

1. Produce a list of numbers that were seperated by commas:

   ```
   have_s.split(',')
   ```
2. Iterate over that list and produce each element with its index in the list:

   ```
   for i, s in enumerate(have_s.split(',')
   ```
3. Given an index and a string, format it to mX=String while removing any extra spaces:

   ```
   'm{}={}'.format(i+1, s.strip())
   ```
4. Join all this together with `&`:

   ```
   '&.join(...)
   ```

#### Test Code:

```
have_s = "245, 246, 171, 172"
want_s = 'm1=245&m2=246&m3=171&m4=172'

new_s = '&'.join('m{}={}'.format(i+1, s.strip())
                 for i, s in enumerate(have_s.split(',')))

assert want_s == new_s
print(new_s)
```

#### Results:

```
m1=245&m2=246&m3=171&m4=172
```

Comment: good one.. was going to answer something similar.. `re.split` so that `strip` is not needed.. and provide starting value as `1` with enumerate so that `i+1` is not needed.. also, can also mention f-string with python 3.6+

Answer (score 1):

With regex, you could just introduce a side effect in your replacement lambda, using the readymade `itertools.count`, initialized to 1.

```
import itertools,re

s = "245, 246, 171, 172"
mval = itertools.count(1)
res = re.sub(r'(\d+),?\s*', lambda m: "m{}={}&".format(next(mval),m.group(1)), s).rstrip("&")
print(res)
```

result (after a corrective strip to remove the remaining `&` from the end):

```
m1=245&m2=246&m3=171&m4=172
```